# Serilog Configurable SQL Server Sink

Tags: sql-server, web-config, serilog, sink

I'm trying to set up a Serilog logger with a SQL Server Sink that is configurable in the `web.config`.

Is there a way to do this in a manner like, for example, with the rolling file sink?

Example:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Logs\Log_File_{Date}.txt" />
```

I have downloaded the `MSSQL` extension for serilog and it works in code like (C#):

```
public ILogger Log = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.MSSqlServer(@"Server=.;Database=LogDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;", "Logs").ReadFrom.AppSettings().CreateLogger();
```

But not like:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer" value="Server=.;Database=LogDatabase;Initial Catalog=Logs;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>
```

Sure there are possibilities to work around this but I'm still wondering if it's possible, for curiosity and better looking code.

Has anyone out there got it to work?

Thankful for replies

Comment: Example of workaround: 
`public static ILogger Log = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.MSSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlLogConnectionString"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlLogTable"]).ReadFrom.AppSettings().CreateLogger();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you're missing:

```
<add key="serilog:using:MSSqlSever" value="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" />
```

You also need to name the `connectionString` argument, and you'll need `tableName` also:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.connectionString" value="Server=.;Database=..."/>
<add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.tableName" value="Logs"/>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the follow up. I've added this to the _README_: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#xml-configuration